# Classes does not working stable

Tags: java, eclipse, class

First class(Player.java);

```
public class Player{
    int[] playercash = {1500,1500,1500,1500,1500,1500};
    int[] playerinvertory = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int[][] playeritemlist = new int[6][20];
    int[][] playeritemdurability = new int[6][20];

    int getCash(int playerid) {
        return playercash[playerid-1];
    }

    void giveCash(int playerid, int add) {
        playercash[playerid-1] += add;
    }
}
```

Second Class(Robot.java);

```
public class Robot {
    Player p = new Player();//Call player class

    void giveCash(int playerid) {
        p.giveCash(1,-3000);
    }
}
```

Main;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        player.giveCash(1, -2000);//1500-2000 = -500
        System.out.println(player.getCash(1)); //Write -500
        robot.giveCash(1); 
        System.out.println(player.getCash(1)); //Write -500
    }
}
```

That is to say, `robot.giveCash` does not give cash. İ think robot class does not call `player` class. I want to write `-3500` but it shows `-500`.

Comment: `Robot` is an existing class in java already. try to not use names for classes which already exist. other example would be a class called `String`

Answer (score 0):

Robot is already existing class in JAVA.

> This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: that is not the actual problem, but i can lead to other problems

Comment: yes, you are right. I didn't noticed that Robot class is creating a new instance each time. now got it whats the problem. Thanks

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but I wonder why it will not create any problem if we will re-use class name which are already exist in JAVA?

Comment: it only interferes, if you want to use the awt Robot in a class called Robot. it then has problems to determine which Robot to use

Answer (score 0):

You make the Mistake, that you create a new `Player` in your Robot class, which is **not** the same as the `Player` you create in your Starter class. Therefore you have 2 different `Players`. You try to add some cash to the `Player` in your Main class, but the `Robot` has a different `Player` he adds cash to. To resolve this problem, pass the player to the `giveCash` method of your Robot class like this:

```
public class Robot{

    void giveCash(int playerid, Player p) {
        p.giveCash(1, -3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Robot` class is creating and updating a separate `Player` instance. One solution is to pass your `Player` instance into the constructor:

```
public class Robot {
    private final Player p;//Call player class

    public Robot(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void giveCash(int playerid) {
        p.giveCash(1,-3000);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
Player player = new Player();
Robot robot = new Robot(player);
```

Comment: wouldn't you need for each player a robot then?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It's not entirely clear, but OP seems to want the robot hardcoded to player 1.

Comment: well okay, that might be true. yet i think, it is better to have 1 robot to handle all players, because of memory and such. still its a possibility that works

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I should point out that your answer doesn't actually pass along `playerid`. And it makes the `Robot` class nearly useless if it would.

Comment: Hard to tell who is right, because we have like no information on how his classes work together and if the player class actually represents 6 players at once. but one thing is sure, both answers provide the output that OP wants